# Stop vim from removing whitespace on save for diff files

Tags: vimdiff, whitespace

I am currently trying to edit a git hunk file (a diff: `.git/addp-hunk-edit.diff`), and to say to git that a line containing whitespace is unchanged it needs to have  (a line with a single space) as its first character. The problem is that Vim removes all whitespace in otherwise empty lines as soon as I save the file!

This only happens on this file type, not for for instance `.vimrc`. How can I manually disable this behavior, and even better, permanently disable it for diff files?

- MacVim 7.4.77, installed via Homebrew.
- [My .vimrc](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/blob/master/common-setup/vim/vimrc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there was nothing explicit in my `.vimrc` that acted on only-whitespace lines and the `diff` syntax file did no such thing either, this had to with my plugins somehow. I find out that I had an EditorConfig file in this project, and in it it had these lines:

```
[*]
# other
#stuff 
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

I then subsequently added a section for diff files

```
[*.diff]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

and voila, everything works as intended :)

Comment: Good call. I *knew* it was editorconfig just by reading the title ;-)

Comment: You should accept your own answer.